# Camel Consumer not reconnecting when ActiveMQ goes down

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

We have multiple consumers connecting to an ActiveMQ broker. When ActiveMQ is shut down or dies the consumers also die. Is there a way to keep them running and to automatically reconnect if ActiveMQ is restarted?

It would also need to work with a failover.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ has failover support with the failover transport.
Refer: http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html
Here's a good article that explains the same.
http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-use-automatic-failover-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use a durable subscription for this:

```
    from(activemq:queue:Q.FOO?durableSubscriptionName=TopicReader1&subscriptionDurable=true")
    .to("....");
```